# Is there a way to not create a sym link if the folder exists

Tags: symlink, ln

I have something like

folder A and when I do `ln -s A a` 
it creates the sym linked folder a 
now if I repeat the command `ln -s A a` I get the dead link a/A

Is there a way that I can have ln fail if the link exists other then wrapping everything in if exists statements ?

Answer (score 2):

If all you're looking for is a single conditional test for a single command, you don't need an `if` statement—just use a *list*.

According to `LESS=+/Lists man bash`:

> ```
>    A  list  is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
>    operators ;, &, &&, or ||, and optionally terminated by one of ;, &, or
>    <newline>.
> ...
>    An AND list has the form
>
>          command1 && command2
>
>    command2  is  executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status
>    of zero.
> ```

Let's say the folder you expect to be there is `mydir` and you want to create a link `mylink2dir` only if the dir exists.  You could use:

```
[ -d mydir ] && ln -s mydir mylink2dir
```

Or equivalently:

```
test -d mydir && ln -s mydir mylink2dir
```

Comment: Thats true at least its compact . You dont have any insight as to why ln functions like that ? It reminds me of OSX s super annoying `cp -R place/ `

Comment: @Prospero, it can be extremely useful to create a link to a file that doesn't exist *yet*.  As to why it was designed that way, it's [part of the Unix Philosophy](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch04s02.html#orthogonality): "Do one thing and do it well."  `ln` exists to create links, not to test for the existence of files.  It's not necessary for a file to exist to have a link made to it, so `ln` doesn't test that. The `test` utility (also known as `[`), on the other hand, has *only* the purpose of testing conditions.  So you can string them together any way you like. Hope that helps.

Comment: its really the fact that ln will do two different things with the same command when one of the outcomes seems to have no application ; unless I guess if your some kind of crazy robot super hero and are recursively ln ing into the unknown ha

Comment: @Prospero, regarding *"ln will do two different things with the same command"* —not really.  Whether the actual file is there or not, all `ln` does is create a new path that points to the same location as the specified path.  The specified path could be a directory, a FIFO, a socket, a block device, a regular file, or even another symlink—or it could not exist.  You're just manipulating *paths*, not files.  How would it be beneficial to have separate commands for each of the cases I've just listed?  It would just make it harder to learn.

Comment: Im not communicating well enough what my confusion is , I dont mean to use up your time ! Its the fact that I can use ln to create a link into a folder then the same command creates a link into that link instead of failing because the folder exists .

Comment: @Prospero, I don't understand that last comment at all, I'm sorry.  A link into that link?  Huh?  Can you give an example command that does what you're talking about?  (And surround it ``with `backticks` for`` better readability.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-n` option to avoid creating a directory. This will overwrite an existing symbolic link, but not create a link inside a directory that's pointed to by an existing symlink.

```
ln -sn A a
```

`ln -n` isn't POSIX but exists on GNU coreutils, BusyBox and *BSD (including OSX).